# Grouping/Clustering Rectangles

Tags: algorithm, sorting, grouping, hierarchical-clustering, aabb

I have a list of shapes (list of points) e.g. rectangles which I want to group/cluster together.

This is what I have:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve.

[image]

### How to do it?

I already looked at some clustering techniques, e.g., kmeans but it seems there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Great question. I added tag [aabb] (axis-aligned bounding box) since the clusters must be axis-aligned bounding boxes.

Comment: "there must be a better way": I doubt it, there is no universal clustering method. And I guess that the results you expect are based on unsaid rules, that no algorithm can guess.

Comment: Probably yes. I make some good progress using hierarchical clustering.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a 'clustering distance' `CD`, i.e. the maximum distance between 2 rectangles at which they would be considered a cluster
2. Compute a second set of rects, each of which correspond to their source rects as follows:
   `[xmin', ymin', xmax', ymax'] = [xmin - CD/2, ymin - CD/2, xmax + CD/2, ymax + CD/2]`
3. Sort all `xmin'`-s and `xmax'`-s and select all pairs of rectangles where either `xmin'` or `xmax'` of the first is within `(xmin', xmax')` range of the second; these are the potential clustering targets
4. Sort all `ymin'`-s and `ymax'`-s and check if the pairs from the previous step do indeed intersect; form clusters
5. Iteratively merge clusters that intersect on at least 1 of the rects they contain; e.g. cluster `(rect #3, rect #10)` and cluster `(rect #10, rect #7)` are to be merged, thus becoming a `(rect #3, rect #7, rect #10)` cluster